# Is it possible to re-use InputStream after client disconnects?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream

My server opens a serversocket on a port then waits for clients to connect in an infinite loop. The first client that connects sends some integers and maps then disconnects, however, the server should still wait for other clients. My issue is, that after correctly receiving these from the first client, I can't open any more scanners and printwriters on the same socket's inputstream/outputstream. The client can connect but cannot send nor recieve any data, I just don't understand what's blocking the stream here:

```
ServerSocket serv = new ServerSocket(port);

while(true) {
    Socket sock = serv.accept();
    ObjectInputStream instream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
    // receiving and handling the data here
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(sock.getInputStream());
    // trying to receive lines here from scanner but it's blocked
}
```

In the client's code I mentioned previously, after sending the maps and other objects, I flush the ObjectOutputStream.

Also, I had a similar problem with scanners before when I closed a scanner on System.in earlier in my code then I couldn't use any scanners on System.in after that, but in this Server code I'm not closing anything after receiving the objects so that's why I don't understand why it's blocked.

So is it possible to re-use the InputStream like this, or should I open another socket for other incoming clients maybe? What should I change if it's not possible?

Comment: Use a new Stream for each client.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels is that not what the code is showing?

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood: indeed it is, but have a look at what he's asking.

Comment: Use a new *thread* for each client. Once you read EOS from an input stream you must close it and stop reading for it. Don't do any I/O in the accept loop, or in the constructor for the thread or Runnable object: do it all in its `run()` method, and that includes constructing object streams.

Comment: And there is no InputStream re-use here, just reuse of a *variable.* And you *are* getting a new socket per client, every time you call accept(). It really isn't clear what you're actually asking.